# Nginx PM2 NodeJS reverse-proxy with SSL gives HTTP 504

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, socket.io, pm2

Once upon a good time, I had a good config for three **NodeJs**, **socket.io** API running on the same **Ubuntu 16.4 LTS VPS** server with **PM2** for process managing and **Nginx** for reverse proxy to three different subdomains.

My installed successfully a **SSL** certificate from **Let's encrypt** and all subdomains are from the same domain (let's say exemple.com) and should be **redirect to https**.

Once I tried to add a fourth subdomain for a non NodeJs application (PHP/laravel), the reverse proxy is not passed anymore and unfortunately i don't have a backup of my old Nginx config.

Now, I am trying to get back my VPS´s harmony with the three old NodeJs apps, but it gives me **504 Gateway Time-out** from **Nginx**.

Here is my config that I think is the same old one:

*This config works fine on chrome, but i'm trying to reach my APIs from mobile and desktop applications.*

```
  # HTTP — redirect all traffic to HTTPS
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  # App1 from port 3000 to sub1.exemple.com
  server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name sub1.exemple.com;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.exemple.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.exemple.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
  }

  # App2 from port 4000 to sub2.exemple.com
  server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name sub2.exemple.com;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub2.exemple.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub2.exemple.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
  }

  # App2 from port 5000 to sub3.exemple.com
  server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name sub3.exemple.com;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub3.exemple.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub3.exemple.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
  }
```

## Update for more info.

Nginx, NodeJs and PM2 doesn't give any errors. logs are clean. Here is what i get when inspect requests.

It succeed when socket request: (Both `wss://` & `https://`)

[image: WSS succeed]

It fail when others request:

[image: HTTP/S fail]

I wanna refer also that the SSL is well installed for each sub and the apps are stable and running on local server without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem and it wasn’t in **not Nginx**, **not PM2**, **not Nodejs** neither in **SSL**, it’s all in the apps i deployed. A problem in Mongodb’s **process** made him **don’t auto-start**. So, the app accept the fist request cause it doesn’t need database intervention and reject the login request after a timeout because the app is already crashed but PM2 restart it and Nginx keeps the sub-domain open to requests.

**FF:** So if you pass by here you probably need to check your app env. ex: SGBD, R/W permission, APIs...

Hope this can help anyone with similar issue.